How to move the title outside of plotting frame in panda plot?
I am facing the problem of titles blocking the graph when I use plot(subplots = True) in Panda.
My code:
df.plot(subplots = True, figsize=(10, 12))
plt.show()

This is what I am getting now:

How can I move the titles of the columns to the top of each subplot?

You tell us the size of your figure, which is good but not the size of your data frame.

axes = df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(10, 12), legend=False)

for ax, column in zip(axes, df.columns):
    ax.set_title(column, loc='center', pad=20)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Try this, tested it on vscode with sample data and it worked.


Sorry It does not work.  I updated my code in the question

edited it... it should work now

You can use the bbox_to_anchor parameter of the legend method to move them outside the plot:
axes = df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(10, 12))

# Adjust legend position for each subplot to be outside the plot
for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))

Result:

The (1, 1) coordinates place the legend to the right of the plot. You can adjust loc and bbox_to_anchor to position the legend as needed.
To move the legends to the top of the plots, you could further use the set_position method to adjust the height of the plots and move the legend to squeeze it between the plots like this:
for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.5))
    ax.set_position([ax.get_position().x0, ax.get_position().y0, ax.get_position().width, ax.get_position().height / 1.5])

